# Javascript Generate Date

Tags: typescript

i need to generate and start, end and deadline date base on a user selection in  a select element, the element has 3 option 1, 2 and 3 month, the idea here is create a loop that is gonna generate and object with this 3 date start, end and deadline, but for each iteration these date most increase 1,2 or 3 months base on what the user select.

Example:

the user select 1 month and the iteration count is gonna be 3
so the the objects most look:

```
Object 1:
start_date: 2017/10/31
end_date: 2017/11/30

Object 2:
start_date: 2017/11/30
end_date: 2017/12/31

Object 3:
start_date: 2017/12/31
end_date: 2018/01/31
```

here is the function:

```
  public DatesGenerator(futercampaign: ICampaign, searchparam: any, i: number): ICampaign {
    let num: number;
    let month: number;
    let tempDate: Date;
    let deadline: Date = new Date(searchparam.start_date);
    let periodicity: Date = new Date(searchparam.start_date);
    if (searchparam.periodicity === 'onemonth') { num = (i * 1); month = 1; } else if (searchparam.periodicity === 'twomonth') { num = (i * 2); month = 2; } else if (searchparam.periodicity === 'threemonth') { num = (i * 3); month = 3; }

      futercampaign.start_date = new Date(periodicity.setMonth(periodicity.getMonth() + num));

      /* Storing the start_date temporarily */
      tempDate = new Date(futercampaign.start_date);

      /* Calculating the End Date */
      futercampaign.end_date = new Date(tempDate.setMonth(tempDate.getMonth() + month));
    /* Calculating the Deadline */
    futercampaign.deadline = new Date(tempDate.setDate(tempDate.getDate() - searchparam.deadline));

    return futercampaign;
  }
```

the searchparam just and object to save the user selection that in this case storage the start_date and the periodicity(1,2 or 3 month).

my problem is that when the user select the last day lets say oct 31 and the next month doesn´t have 31 day too jump that month in this case november and go to december 31.

Comment: can you use `moment.js`?

Comment: yes i can use it.